# Format of text within Tabular environment

Tags: formatting

I want to make the words "words words words" be directly below `n^k`. What I have tried so far has not worked. That is, `\newline`, `\\`, and `\underset{}` cannot accomplish what I desire.

#### Example Code

```
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{ | l | l | p{5cm} |}
    \hline
     & Order Matters & Order Doesn't Matter  \\ \hline
    Repetition Allowed & $\displaystyle{n^k} $\par{ words words words}& $\displaystyle {n+k-1 \choose k-1}$ \\ \hline
    No Repetition Allowed& $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ & ${n \choose k}$  \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: As a sidenote: `\par` does _not_ take an argument like `\par{these braces are superfluous}`.

Comment: How does \par know when to stop creating a paragraph environment then?

Comment: @Ozera: Use a new tabular row or a `p` column for that

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thank you! Your answer and Werner's were very helpful.

Comment: `\par` is a TeX primitive that tells the compiler when to start a new paragraph by ending horizontal mode. (Hence, it does not need to know the end of a paragraph.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use `\par` inside a fixed-width `p`-column. Here is a toned-down implementation of your `tabular`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{ l c c }
    \toprule
     & Order Matters & Order Doesn't Matter \\
    \cmidrule{2-3}
    Repetition Allowed & $\underset{\text{words words words}}{n^k}$ & $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$ \\[.5\normalbaselineskip]
    No Repetition Allowed & $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ & $\binom{n}{k}$ \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

It uses `\binom` from [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) instead of the plain-TeX `\choose`. A `\displaystyle` version is available as `\dbinom`.

---

Another option that allows for paragraph breaks as needed (with the aid of [`varwidth`](http://ctan.org/pkg/varwidth). A fixed-width column is created using `L{<width>}` which will produce a `L`eft-aligned column no wider than `<width>`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,booktabs,varwidth,collcell}

\newcommand{\fixedwidthcolumn}[1]{%
  \begin{varwidth}[t]{\fcolwidth}%
    \raggedright
    \strut#1\strut
  \end{varwidth}}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\gdef\fcolwidth{#1}\collectcell\fixedwidthcolumn}l<{\endcollectcell}}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{ l c c }
    \toprule
     & Order Matters & Order Doesn't Matter \\
    \cmidrule{2-3}
    Repetition Allowed & $\underset{\text{words words words}}{n^k}$ & $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$ \\[.5\normalbaselineskip]
    No Repetition Allowed & $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ & $\binom{n}{k}$ \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}

  \bigskip

  \begin{tabular}{ L{130pt} c c }
    \toprule
     & Order Matters & Order Doesn't Matter \\
    \cmidrule{2-3}
    Repetition Allowed & $\underset{\text{words words words}}{n^k}$ & $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$ \\[.5\normalbaselineskip]
    No Repetition Allowed & $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ & $\binom{n}{k}$ \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}

  \bigskip

  \begin{tabular}{ L{130pt} c c }
    \toprule
     & Order Matters & Order Doesn't Matter \\
    \cmidrule{2-3}
    Some text that is long and will most like span multiple lines (but be not wider than \texttt{130pt}) & 
      $\underset{\text{words words words}}{n^k}$ & $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$ \\
    No Repetition Allowed & $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ & $\binom{n}{k}$ \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to use paragraphs in this? If there is too much text it expands the boxes too much and runs off the page.

Comment: @Ozera: Yes, but you'll have to use a fixed-width `p`-column, or a boxed structure like `\parbox{<width>}{<stuff>}`, or perhaps an `X`-column from [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx). You could also use the [`makecell` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/makecell) to make cell-specific `tabular`s.

Comment: I attempted a fix like http://mathurl.com/mkhlnkb but as you can see, the text decided to do whatever it wanted. Have an idea ?

Comment: @Ozera: I've added another option which might help you - using a `L{<width>}` column.

Comment: @Ozera: I see that you're trying to introduce line-breaks in the part of the `tabular` that is actually math. That's not possible in the way you use it. For this it's easier to use a manual line-break by means of `\substack{... \\ ...}` (also provided by [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)).

Comment: I see. I've got it working now. Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 2):

This uses an extra `p(arbox)` column, but does not center the text (as this was not requested)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{ | l | p{3cm} | p{5cm} |}
    \hline
     & Order Matters & Order Doesn't Matter  \\ \hline
    Repetition Allowed & $\displaystyle{n^k}$ \linebreak words words words & $\displaystyle {n+k-1 \choose k-1}$ \\ \hline
    No Repetition Allowed& $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ & ${n \choose k}$  \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]